# gdb use calculation of one command as an argument to another

Tags: memory, gdb, stack

I'm trying to show a memory print out of the current stack frame, but right now what I have to do is laborious:

```
# Find out how big the current frame is:
(gdb) print/x $ebp - $esp
$1 = 0x4
# Use that in a display:
(gdb) x/4x $ebp
```

I'd love to use the `define` command to make it so this just happens after every step, so I have a constant awareness of the stack frame.

Doing things like these:

```
(gdb) x/$1x $ebp
(gdb) x/($1)x $ebp
```

hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [GDB](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gdb), command `x` is used to examine the memory with the arguments as follows,

```
x
x address
x/nfu address
```

Where `n` is repeat count, `f` is display format & `u` is unit size;

```
(gdb) p/x $rsp
$4 = 0x7fffffffe248
(gdb) x/4x 0x7fffffffe248
0x7fffffffe248: 0xffffe4e5  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
(gdb) x/$4
0x7fffffffe248: 0xffffe4e5
(gdb) x/$4x 
Value can't be converted to integer.
(gdb) x/$4 $rsp
A syntax error in expression, near `$rsp'.
(gdb) x/$_
0x7fffffffe248: 0xffffe4e5
```

Observe the last command `x/$_` in which after `x`, the last address examined is available for use in expressions using `$_` variable.

EDIT: The memory content of address produced by variable `$_` is given by variable `$__`.

Comment: `$_`! Who would have thunk it.